# Android: Using StreetViewPanoramaView in XML

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments, google-street-view

Anyone know if there's a way to place a StreetViewPanoramaView in XML? I have a map fragment already and am overlaying a view on top of that, but it looks like whenever I use com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView in XML and call onStreetViewPanoramaReady in my MapFragment, I never get a response for initializing my Panorama.

Every example I can find on GitHub and from Google seems to create the view in code and then attach it to an activity. I ended up trying to create a StreetViewPanoramaView in code with the options set in my MapFragment, but still couldn't get the callback. If I use a StreetViewPanoramaFragment, I can retrieve the panorama fine through the callback and can go about what I'm trying to do, but I don't really want to nest a StreetViewPanoramaFragment as an overlay on a MapFragment if I can avoid it.

What is working for me right now in my MapFragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
    View overlay = inflater.inflate( R.layout.view_map_overlay, parent, false );

    mIndoorSelector = (SeekBar) overlay.findViewById( R.id.indoor_level_selector );
    mIndoorMinLevel = (TextView) overlay.findViewById( R.id.indoor_min_level );
    mIndoorMaxLevel = (TextView) overlay.findViewById( R.id.indoor_max_level );

    parent.addView(overlay);

    hideFloorLevelSelector();

    mPanoramaFragment = (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById( R.id.steet_view_panorama );
    mPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
            mPanorama = streetViewPanorama;
            showStreetView( new LatLng( 40.7506, -73.9936 ) );
        }
    });


    return parent;
}
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/indoor_min_level"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/indoor_level_selector"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/indoor_max_level"
        android:text="10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/steet_view_panorama"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaFragment"/>
```

Comment: And what's wrong with this code? Any error? NullPointerException?   MapFragment - you mean, you are extending com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in this class?

Comment: I'm extending MapFragment for this class, yes. The code I posted is fine and working. What I'm looking to do is use a StreetViewPanoramicView instead of a fragment.

Comment: Look on my last edition of answer, i created simple gist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this view to your layout

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView
    android:id="@+id/steet_view_panorama"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And in onCreateView

```
mStreetViewPanoramaView = (StreetViewPanoramaView) findViewById(R.id.steet_view_panorama);
mStreetViewPanoramaView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mStreetViewPanoramaView.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
        panorama.setPosition(new LatLng(55.758818, 37.620587));
        mPanorama = panorama;
    }
});
```

Don't forget to forward lifecycle methods to this view, according to https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanoramaView

Here is a gist with a whole Activity with StreetViewPanoramaView
https://gist.github.com/pengrad/bfe2588a9730779db6fb

Comment: Awesome, it was that onCreate portion for the view that I was missing. Your code snippet worked perfectly. Thanks.